# Expression for sample variance of a Bernoulli variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,..,X_n$ be independent Bernoulli variables with a shared distribution.

$
\overline{X}(n) := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$

With regard to the **sample variance** estimator $S^2(n)$, the book states:

> The explanation is that $S^2(n) = \overline{X}(n)[1-\overline{X}(n)]$ for variables $X_i$ that take on only the values 0 and 1. It is a matter of simple algebra to verify this fact.

Yet I am failing to verify this fact. Could anyone lay out the algebra for me? I am trying to transform

$S^2(n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n[X_i-\overline{X}(n)]^2$

into above expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $X_i$'s are $0-1$ valued we have $X_i^{2}=X_i$. With this information it should be easy for you to verify the identity.

> $$\frac  1n \sum (X_i-\overline {X_n})^{2}=\frac 1 n\sum X_i^{2}-(\overline {X_n})^{2}$$ $$=\frac 1 n\sum X_i-(\overline {X_n})^{2}$$ $$=\overline {X_n}-(\overline {X_n})^{2}=(\overline {X_n})(1-\overline {X_n}).$$ The first equality is standard text book material.

Comment: Ah! How can I be this dumb. Anyway, thanks a lot, that helped.