# Distribution of sample variance of Bernoulli variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I am facing the following problem, given $X_1 ... X_n$ a random sample of $Bernoulli(\theta)$ variables find the distribution of the sample variance $S^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i(\bar{X} - X_i)^2$.

I have demonstrated that $S^2 = \bar{X} (1 - \bar{X})$ and i know $\bar{nX}$ has distribution $Binomial (n, \theta)$ but I have not been able to deduce the distribution of $S^2$.

Comment: " *I have demonstrated that* $S^2 = \bar{X} (1 - \bar{X})$ ": Are you sure that this true?

Comment: @callculus Isn't it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546180/expression-for-sample-variance-of-a-bernoulli-variable  agrees on the equality

Comment: It seems so, but I haven´t checked it. But I think the distribution of $S^2$ is so unhandsome that usually the central limit theorem is used.

Comment: You can get a proper bar across a wider expression, e.g. in $\overline{nX}$, using `\overline` instead of `\bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You know the distribution of $\overline X$ and you’ve correctly determined that $S^2$ is a function of $\overline X$. Then the distribution of $S^2$ is just the composition of the two: The probability of a value of $S^2$ is the sum of the probabilities of the values of $\overline X$ that are its preimages; that is, for all integers $k$ from $0$ to $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ we have:

$$
P\left(S^2=\frac kn\left(1-\frac kn\right)\right)=P\left(\overline X=\frac kn\lor\overline X=1-\frac kn\right)=
\begin{cases}
\binom nk\theta^k(1-\theta)^k&k=\frac n2\;,\\
\binom nk\left(\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}+\theta^{n-k}(1-\theta)^k\right)&\text{otherwise}\;.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: "otherwise" seems to raise a variety of issues, as does having an answer in terms of $k$

Comment: @Henry: I'd forgotten to normalize $k$; all the $k$s should have been $\frac kn$ in the upper line. I've also made the range of $k$ explicit now. Is it OK now? Or is there a more fundamental issue? I'm not sure what you meant by issues being raised by "otherwise" and by the answer being in terms of $k$.

Comment: The point I was aiming at is that there are a lot of "otherwise" values of $c$ for which $P(S^2=c) =0$.  There are also cases where two different values of $k$ correspond to the same $S^2$.  So you could instead have something like $P(S^2=c)$ being $\binom n{n/2}\left(\theta (1-\theta)\right)^{n/2}$ when $c=\frac14$ and $n$ is an even integer; being $\binom n{n\left(1-\sqrt{1-4c^2}\right)/2}\left(\theta (1-\theta)\right)^{n(1-\sqrt{1-4c^2})/2}\left(\theta^{n\sqrt{1-4c^2}} +(1-\theta)^{n\sqrt{1-4c^2}}\right)$ when $n-n\sqrt{1-4c}$ is a non-negative  even integer $<n$; and being $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Henry: I think the cases where two different values of $k$ correspond to the same $S^2$ are correctly covered in the answer. You're right that "otherwise" was imprecise; I was relying on it being clear what values of $k$ it makes sense to substitute. I made that explicit in response to your first comment. I think it should be OK now?

Comment: Well, I'm still not saying that it's $0$ otherwise. Perhaps we just have different ambitions for rigour and explicitness :-)

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $\overline{X} \approx \mathcal{N}(\theta,\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n})$ by the Central Limit Theorem, if we apply the second-order delta method to $g(\theta) = \theta(1-\theta)$, it follows that we can get a good continuous approximation to the PMF $f_{S^{2}}$ of $S^{2}$ via

$ f_{S^{2}}(y) \approx \frac{|C|}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{n}{ (\frac{B}{C})^{2} + 4(Cy - \frac{A}{C})  }}\left( e^{\frac{-n}{8\sigma^{2}}(\sqrt{(\frac{B}{C})^{2} + 4(Cy - \frac{A}{C}) } - \frac{B}{C})^{2}  } + e^{\frac{-n}{8\sigma^{2}}(\sqrt{(\frac{B}{C})^{2} + 4(Cy - \frac{A}{C}) } + \frac{B}{C})^{2}  }  \right)  1_{0 < y < 1/4}   $

where here $A = \overline{X}(1-\overline{X})$, $B = 1 - 2\overline{X}$, $C = -1$ and $\sigma^{2} = \overline{X}(1-\overline{X})$.

Though this is not the exact distribution of $S^{2}$ as given in Joriki's answer, you'll find this to be a very good continuous approximation to the sampling distribution of $S^{2}$, even when $n$ is quite small.